# How to identify extra value error in a csv using R

Tags: r, csv

I am looking for a method and not a code as a solution. Any suggestions are welcome.

Here is a sample data that is corrupted (commas should not have been there). By the way I don't have any control over the csv files I receive.

```
A    B         C
1.1  1,859.3  52.1
0    12.2     123
```

In csv format it looks like:

```
A,B,C
1.1 ,1,859.3,52.1
0,12.2,123
```

But then, when I read it in using R, row 1 has an extra column and that is an error. Is there any comfortable way to identify if the csv file has any error like this extra column. I could write a bunch of nested loops that parse through length of each row but then I am talking about 1000 csvs with 100000 rows. It will take for ever. Please help. Any method is appreciated.

Comment: `?count.fields` is probably helpful as it will farm out the checking of each line length to compiled C code.

Comment: You have 2 options. 1. Use different separator for field `(like |, or \t)` or second option could be to read it using `read.fwf` which supports fixed width columns.

Comment: great! thank you. I will try and will post what I found.

Answer (score 1):

Save to csv using a different separator, e.g. `;`

Then you would have something like

```
A;B;C
1.1;1,859.3;52.1
0;12.2;123
```

The code is simple

```
write.csv(..., sep = ";")
read.csv( ..., sep = ";")
```

Comment: Well I am talking about a massive data set that we import as 100s of csv. I have no control over how the csv is generated with , or ;